# how to get clear image in UI button in Unity

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, button

I dont know how to get clear image in UI button in Unity, when cell interactable = false and dont have icon, its become white. But when I change color image become black. I tried changing all the colors, and only 2 colors:color and disabled color. When I change color to black, cell became black, then change to invisible image dont show. When change disabled color to black, icon became black, then change to invisible, icon dont show. [simple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbvmx.png)    [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSCQs.png)[Colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rVtv.png)
[Black 1 button and others normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z2NR.png)
Code doesn`t show completely.

```
    void Human()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Field.Length; i++)
        {
            if (MarkedSpaces[i] == -10)
            {
                Field[i].interactable = true;
            }
        }
    }
    void Bot()
    {                
    label:
        int value = Random.Range(0, 8);
        if (MarkedSpaces[value] == -10 & CountTurn !<= 8)
        {
            Field[value].image.sprite = PlayIcon[WhoTurn];
            Field[value].GetComponentInParent<Button>().interactable = false;
            EndTurn();
        }
        else if (CountTurn !<= 8)
        {
            goto label;
        }
    }
    public void Button(int WhichNumber)
    {
        Field[WhichNumber].image.sprite = PlayIcon[WhoTurn];
        Field[WhichNumber].interactable = false;
        EndTurn();
    }
```

I want clear image in Button In Unity.

Comment: doesnt look like any of the colours are set to transparaent

Comment: In Button inspector I change color.

Comment: right but in the non linked pictures i dont see them as transparaent they all look like they have a 255 alpha

Comment: when i click on button, image set on button, but donesn`t show

Comment: for bot i create delay on 3 seconds and interactable = false and it`s show 3 seconds white cell

Comment: 1 problem per question either you  want a clear image or youy dont..

Comment: want clear image

Comment: right, so, check the settings on the texture/sprite you are putting on your button

Comment: i check this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rVtv.png)

Comment: and to you this makes something clear - to me (so far the only one talking to you) it does not make anything clear as to what you think the problem is.  I see an X and an O both of which look clear - and that is the properties of the in game item.. whats the prioperties of the actual sprite/texture.

Comment: when delay, button  its become white, because color in inspestor white, then i change 1 button to color backround. When exist delay all button white and 1 button normal, but when i set icon its become black.

Comment: when change color in inspector its change color sprite

Comment: sprite simple grey color

Comment: I add this image